# Using standard Debugger Visualizer provided with emguCV

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visualizer

I never used custom visualizer and I am wondering what do I do wrong. According to Microsoft help I just need to copy .dll to two directories. I did this and I got below exception.
C# + EmguCV3.3.0 + visual studio 2017.

[image]

I added it also as a reference to the solution. What do I need to do more?

Comment: Is this a compile time exception?

Comment: Nope. This is... how to say it "debug time exception". It's runtime but in debug mode. executed line by line. It appears when Debugger Visualizer is being clicked on the image object in the code.

Comment: Can you share your code piece which throws exception?

Comment: It's not my code that throws an exception. It's this Debugger. It throws this exception anywhere I use It. On any Image objcet in the code. 
I asked this question because I don't know... how does this Debugger_Visualizer work. It's not even a part of my code. so do I need a reference to it? It's so hard to find out how should be configured  or used.
I attach the link to EmguCV site about this debbuger. according to them it just should work :D
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Debugger_Visualizer

Comment: I see. I'd try to run Visual Studio as administrator. Good luck!

Comment: You’re probably missing the opencv libraries in your output directory, it also could be caused by a platform mismatch, if you are using the x64 libraries make sure your project is set only to build for x64.
 I’ve read the tutorials:
doc: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp 
Video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PoonbKW7YI

Comment: @PinDoll Is it related to the platform architecture? Have you downloaded  the right one x86 or x64?

Comment: Yup. I used the rigth version - x64.

Comment: I didn't download it separetely. it was in the bundle with libraries that work. I am using them... the only thing that doesn't work is this visualizer.
Could anyone tell me how to properly install it step by step... because maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

It was the x64 package for me. The EMGU installer for x64 doesn't ask you if you want to install the visualizer. You need to copy it from the bin folder to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` folder yourself